# formData get() Doesn't seem to work in Safari

Tags: safari

This is my code. It works in Firefox and Chrome but not Safari. I get no errors.

```
<script>
var cleanData = new FormData();
cleanData.append("test", "test");
alert(cleanData.get("test"));
</script>
```

Does anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 6):

Apparently, Safari has no means of getting values stored in FormData objects at this time. There is no workaround at this time, and apparently it's not practical to polyfill.

Sorry :(

Notes:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get#Browser_compatibility
https://www.bountysource.com/issues/27573236-is-it-possible-to-polyfill-missing-formdata-methods

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by conditionally (if Safari is the browser) iterating through the **elements** property of an actual **form**.  For all other browser, my wrapper just iterates through **FormData entries()**.  The end result of my function, in either case, is a simple javascript object (JSON) which amounts to name/value pairs.

```
function FormDataNameValuePairs(FormName)
{
  var FormDaytaObject={};
  var FormElement=$('#'+FormName).get(0);

  if (IsSafariBrowser())
  {
    var FormElementCollection=FormElement.elements;
    //console.log('namedItem='+FormElementCollection.namedItem('KEY'));
    var JQEle,EleType;
    for (ele=0; (ele < FormElementCollection.length); ele++)
    {
      JQEle=$(FormElementCollection.item(ele));
      EleType=JQEle.attr('type');

      // https://github.com/jimmywarting/FormData/blob/master/FormData.js
      if ((! JQEle.attr('name')) ||
          (((EleType == 'checkbox') || (EleType == 'radio')) &&
           (! JQEle.prop('checked'))))
        continue;
      FormDaytaObject[JQEle.attr('name')]=JQEle.val();
    }
  }
  else
  {
    var FormDayta=new FormData(FormElement);
    for (var fld of FormDayta.entries())
      FormDaytaObject[fld[0]]=fld[1];
  }

  return FormDaytaObject;
}
```

where IsSafariBrowser() is implemented by whatever your favorite method is, but I chose this:

```
function IsSafariBrowser()
{
  var VendorName=window.navigator.vendor;
  return ((VendorName.indexOf('Apple') > -1) &&
          (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') > -1));
}
```

Example usage in OP's case, assuming that you have an actual form called CleanDataForm instead of creating a FormData from scratch:

```
var cleanData=FormDataNameValuePairs('CleanDataForm');
alert(cleanData.test);
```